# How do I add a button click event to my own button in Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, visual-studio

Is there a way to add a button click event to a button I create myself?

I am using Visual Studio Premium 2013. I was trying to customise the appearance of the standard button control from the toolbox but it wasnt doing what I wanted (there were issues with border-radius and other things). So I decided to make my own button. Its a div, styled with this css and wrapped with an anchor tag:

```
<a href="#"><div id="loginBtn">Login</div></a>                    

#loginBtn {
    width: 60px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: #3B647F;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px gray;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.75;
}
```

But how do I add a click event to this button? I tried instead using a hyperlink control like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hyp1" runat="server"><div id="loginBtn">Login</div></asp:HyperLink>
```

But I couldnt find a way to add a click event to a hyperlink.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: add the onClick event to the div?

Comment: I tried double clicking the div to create a click event but it didnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `asp:LinkButton`, you can add `OnClickEvent`. You can read how to do it in this [MSDN Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.click(v=vs.110).aspx)

**ASPX:**

```
 <asp:LinkButton id="LinkButton1" 
           Text="Click Me" 
           OnClick="LinkButton_Click" 
           runat="server"/>
```

**Code behind:**

```
  void LinkButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
  {
     Label1.Text="You clicked the link button";
  }
```